# Can we use previous version msi/wxs file to generate new upgrade msi package?

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer

I am sorry, I have to say I am a newbie to wix toolset and wxs related knowledge...

Currently, we are developing a windows desktop application. Everytime we release our product version, we give our binary files to a build team, and build team help us to generate the upgrade .msi package, which will take a LONG time.

I have a look about wix toolset, and find if we have no installation process change during the msi installation process, we could use dark.exe command to generate the wxs file from old version msi pakcage, and then change the new GUID, product name and product version, etc, we can then change the wxs to new upgrade msi package again with candle and light command. There is no need for build team to generate the msi package for us any more for some easy cases....

Am I correct? if yes, we could use some automatic way to handle some application upgrade work for some easy upgrade cases....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you have in your Product tag of the resultant wxs file a `*` for the id attribute will generate a new guid on each build of the installer.

```
<Product Id="*"
         Version="1.2"
         UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

     <MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"
                   DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeErrorMessage)" />

</Product>
```

As long as you keep the UpgradeCode static it will automatically un-install the previous version and then install the new one for you. The `AllowSameVersionUpgrades` allows this to work for minor version changes although if the installer is large and takes a long time to install you should probably look at patching.